# Gostaria de achar a distancia em km entre dois markers como posso fazer?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Tenho dois markers nesse código e quero achar a distância em quilômetros entre eles.

```
private void setUpMap() {
    Database_Congregacao database_congregacao = new Database_Congregacao(this);
    int tamanho = 0;
    int size = 0;
    tamanho = database_congregacao.Buscar_Ultimas_Coordenadas().size() - 1;
    size = tamanho;

    Float lt = Float.parseFloat(latitude);
    Float lon = Float.parseFloat(longitude);
    String nome_congregacao = Activity_informacao_congregacao.this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("nome_congregacao");
    //Marker do LOcal do evento
    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lt,lon)).title(nome_congregacao).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker3)));

    //Marker da localizacao do usuario
    Marker marker2 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(database_congregacao.Buscar_Ultimas_Coordenadas().get(size).getLatitude(),database_congregacao.Buscar_Ultimas_Coordenadas().get(size).getLongitude())).title("Minha Localização").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker5)));

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lt, lon), 12));
    marker.showInfoWindow();
    marker2.showInfoWindow();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Como você pergunta apenas pela distância entre dois pontos, você pode usar [`distanceTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)) da classe [`Location`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html). Conforme a documentação, ele retorna a distância aproximada em metros entre os dois pontos.

Então, para calcular em KM, algo como isto irá lhe ajudar:

```
public double calculaDistanciaEmKM(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) { 
    final Location start = new Location("Start Point"); 
    start.setLatitude(lat1); 
    start.setLongitude(lon1);

    final Location finish = new Location("Finish Point"); 
    finish.setLatitude(lat2); 
    finish.setLongitude(lon2); 
    final float distance = start.distanceTo(finish);

    return distance / 1000;
}
```

Para informações detalhadas sobre a distância, trânsito, etc., considere olhar a API  [`Directions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/).